# Pandas read excel : ValueError

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read an exec file into pandas (0.24.1) with the following command:

```
import pandas as pd
file_df=pd.read_excel('c:\\temp\\file.xlsx')
```

I get this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

What can be the possible reason/solution? 
The file is an xlsx file which opens in excel. One strange thing I noticed if I open the file in excel and save it without changing anything the saved file is read by Pandas without error, but not the original file! 
(I'm using Win10 office 365)

Comment: I think it would be almost impossible to help you without the xlsx file. The file is probably slightly corrupted, when you save it, office rewrites the xml (all office files are actually xmls) and the new xml has the correct structure, so pandas can successfully read it.

Comment: I think in your excel, there are cells which have space/non-numeric character and it tries to convert to integers. Could be due to encoding charset. Have a look at which charset the original one has.

Comment: Both files (original and corrected) are in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your general intent is to investigate what causes pandas to fail reading the xlsx file, you don't need an actual solution because just re-saving the file fixes the issue.

My suggestion is as follows.
save the working version as fixed.xlsx

1. rename .xlsx to .rar or .zip so you have file.zip and fixed.zip
2. extract the archive to file folder and fixed folder.
3. Compare the folders with a software (I use Beyond Compare however any other would do fine)
4. I suspect the difference would be in /xl/worksheets, so compare this folder first.
5. You might not understand the meaning of the differences between the xml files. If that is the case, post the differences here and some one will explain you (hopefully) what is the actual difference between the files

hope I helped

Comment: You are correct. I've a workaround to open/save the files with win32com module before importing, but this is not very professional. In my view this is a problem of Pandas, and as such there should be a solution there. I'm analyzing the format of the files as you suggested. The worksheet is very different, between the two versions.

Comment: This is the header of the non-working file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
<dimension ref="A1:T801"/>
<sheetViews><sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
</sheetView></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15"/>
<sheetData>

It seems it refers to some old formatting.

Comment: The header of the version which is read by Pandas contains the following as extra:
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" 
xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" 
xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" 
xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" 
xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" 
xr:uid="{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}">

Comment: my guess is that pandas has difficulty with reading the old format, and when you save the file manually from excel it fixes the issue.
I assume pandas contributors will not prioritize this bug because it is an old format. If you want an automated solution you can use pywin32 package or perhaps openpyxl package to open and save the file before pandas reads it.